# How to make 2 Euros with smaller coins

Tags: logical-deduction, number-theory, coins

You are given n > 0 of each of the standard denomination Euro coins: 1 ct, 2 ct, 5 ct, 10 ct, 20 ct, 50 ct, 1 Euro, 2 Euro.

What is the smallest n such that it is impossible to select n coins that make exactly 2 Euros?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 201

> Proof by induction: Seed at n=1 in the obvious way. Let n be one less than the smallest impossible number. Then n admits a split. If that contains any of the 2p,10p,20p,1Eur,2Eur coins we can replace that with two of half its denomination, a contradiction. If it contains three ore more of either 5p or 50p we can replace them by 1p,2x2p,10p or 10p,2x20p,1Eur, respectively, contradiction. Otherwise we have max 2x5p + 2x50p and the rest must be 1p, at least 90 of them. If they are not all 1p, take a 50p and 2 1p and replace them with 2p + 10p +2x20p or a 5p and a 1p and replace them with 3x2p. $\square$

Comment: The proof seems valid, but you don't seem to use the "obvious seed" in any way, and I really can't see any induction happening anywhere. Rather, you seem to be directly (non-inductively) deducing the necessary properties of any doable n where n+1 is impossible.

Comment: @Bass If the seeding is superfluous, then please explain to me why the proof doesn't work unchanged for 1Eur 99p.

Comment: Certainly the proof still applies, unchanged, to every doable n where n+1 is not doable.

Comment: @Bass Let me rephrase: If the let's call it for no particular reason at all the step if it still works unchanged then why can't we draw the same unchanged conclusion?

Comment: You know very well why you need to check n=1 in particular, you just don't bother to explain it in your answer, nor in any of your educational and most witty comments. n=1 is one of the boundary values where you might find the smallest impossible n, so you need to check that value in particular. Checking n=1 doesn't affect the neighbouring value of n=2 (or any other n) at all, so calling n=1 a "seed" is misleading at best. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Bass Getting a whiff of diapproval there. I'm sorry, I did mean to slightly annoy you but really only to make you work it out youself since you clearly know your stuff and were just having a bad day at the office. I looked up the technical term for seed, apparently it's base case or initial case.

Comment: It would be a seed, base case, or initial case (all are fine) if you were doing induction, which you aren't. In an induction proof, you prove something for some value of n, and then *use that result* to prove the same for n+1. The only thing your answer says about n=2 is in the (omitted) deduction step where "any combination that isn't all 1-cent coins cannot be a doable value that is one less than an impossible value." Notice how the (im)possibility of n=1 isn't a factor in this deduction? That's because this is a proof by enumeration, with some very clever grouping taking care of most cases.

Comment: @Bass But it is clearly induction. Maybe I phrased it a bit non standard. Inductioni can always be put in the equivalent form "If it weren't true for all n there would have to be a smallest n for which it fails"

Comment: In mathematics, a [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) means a very specific method of proving a theorem for all natural numbers, and it always consists of an induction hypothesis, an induction step, and a base case. If you insist on calling some other methods "proof by induction", then sure, go ahead, but be advised that you are using the term in a misleading manner.

Answer (score 2):

To demonstrate that Paul Panzer's accepted numeric answer is correct, here is a list of ways to select the coins.

The format is:
Total coins: (quantity x denomination) + (quantity x denomination) + ...

On each line, the math equals 2.00

> 1: (1 * 2.00)
>  2: (2 * 1.00)
>  3: (1 * 1.00) + (2 * 0.50)
>  4: (4 * 0.50)
>  5: (1 * 1.00) + (1 * 0.50) + (2 * 0.20) + (1 * 0.10)
>  6: (1 * 1.00) + (5 * 0.20)
>  7: (2 * 0.50) + (5 * 0.20)
>  8: (2 * 0.50) + (4 * 0.20) + (2 * 0.10)
>  9: (1 * 0.50) + (7 * 0.20) + (1 * 0.10)
>  10: (10 * 0.20)
>  11: (9 * 0.20) + (2 * 0.10)
>  12: (8 * 0.20) + (4 * 0.10)
>  13: (7 * 0.20) + (6 * 0.10)
>  14: (6 * 0.20) + (8 * 0.10)
>  15: (5 * 0.20) + (10 * 0.10)
>  16: (4 * 0.20) + (12 * 0.10)
>  17: (3 * 0.20) + (14 * 0.10)
>  18: (2 * 0.20) + (16 * 0.10)
>  19: (1 * 0.20) + (18 * 0.10)
>  20: (20 * 0.10)
>  21: (19 * 0.10) + (2 * 0.05)
>  22: (18 * 0.10) + (4 * 0.05)
>  23: (17 * 0.10) + (6 * 0.05)
>  24: (16 * 0.10) + (8 * 0.05)
>  25: (15 * 0.10) + (10 * 0.05)
>  26: (14 * 0.10) + (12 * 0.05)
>  27: (13 * 0.10) + (14 * 0.05)
>  28: (12 * 0.10) + (16 * 0.05)
>  29: (11 * 0.10) + (18 * 0.05)
>  30: (10 * 0.10) + (20 * 0.05)
>  31: (9 * 0.10) + (22 * 0.05)
>  32: (8 * 0.10) + (24 * 0.05)
>  33: (7 * 0.10) + (26 * 0.05)
>  34: (6 * 0.10) + (28 * 0.05)
>  35: (5 * 0.10) + (30 * 0.05)
>  36: (4 * 0.10) + (32 * 0.05)
>  37: (3 * 0.10) + (34 * 0.05)
>  38: (2 * 0.10) + (36 * 0.05)
>  39: (1 * 0.10) + (38 * 0.05)
>  40: (40 * 0.05)
>  41: (2 * 0.10) + (34 * 0.05) + (5 * 0.02)
>  42: (1 * 0.10) + (36 * 0.05) + (5 * 0.02)
>  43: (38 * 0.05) + (5 * 0.02)
>  44: (2 * 0.10) + (32 * 0.05) + (10 * 0.02)
>  45: (1 * 0.10) + (34 * 0.05) + (10 * 0.02)
>  46: (36 * 0.05) + (10 * 0.02)
>  47: (2 * 0.10) + (30 * 0.05) + (15 * 0.02)
>  48: (1 * 0.10) + (32 * 0.05) + (15 * 0.02)
>  49: (34 * 0.05) + (15 * 0.02)
>  50: (2 * 0.10) + (28 * 0.05) + (20 * 0.02)
>  51: (1 * 0.10) + (30 * 0.05) + (20 * 0.02)
>  52: (32 * 0.05) + (20 * 0.02)
>  53: (2 * 0.10) + (26 * 0.05) + (25 * 0.02)
>  54: (1 * 0.10) + (28 * 0.05) + (25 * 0.02)
>  55: (30 * 0.05) + (25 * 0.02)
>  56: (2 * 0.10) + (24 * 0.05) + (30 * 0.02)
>  57: (1 * 0.10) + (26 * 0.05) + (30 * 0.02)
>  58: (28 * 0.05) + (30 * 0.02)
>  59: (2 * 0.10) + (22 * 0.05) + (35 * 0.02)
>  60: (1 * 0.10) + (24 * 0.05) + (35 * 0.02)
>  61: (26 * 0.05) + (35 * 0.02)
>  62: (2 * 0.10) + (20 * 0.05) + (40 * 0.02)
>  63: (1 * 0.10) + (22 * 0.05) + (40 * 0.02)
>  64: (24 * 0.05) + (40 * 0.02)
>  65: (2 * 0.10) + (18 * 0.05) + (45 * 0.02)
>  66: (1 * 0.10) + (20 * 0.05) + (45 * 0.02)
>  67: (22 * 0.05) + (45 * 0.02)
>  68: (2 * 0.10) + (16 * 0.05) + (50 * 0.02)
>  69: (1 * 0.10) + (18 * 0.05) + (50 * 0.02)
>  70: (20 * 0.05) + (50 * 0.02)
>  71: (2 * 0.10) + (14 * 0.05) + (55 * 0.02)
>  72: (1 * 0.10) + (16 * 0.05) + (55 * 0.02)
>  73: (18 * 0.05) + (55 * 0.02)
>  74: (2 * 0.10) + (12 * 0.05) + (60 * 0.02)
>  75: (1 * 0.10) + (14 * 0.05) + (60 * 0.02)
>  76: (16 * 0.05) + (60 * 0.02)
>  77: (2 * 0.10) + (10 * 0.05) + (65 * 0.02)
>  78: (1 * 0.10) + (12 * 0.05) + (65 * 0.02)
>  79: (14 * 0.05) + (65 * 0.02)
>  80: (2 * 0.10) + (8 * 0.05) + (70 * 0.02)
>  81: (1 * 0.10) + (10 * 0.05) + (70 * 0.02)
>  82: (12 * 0.05) + (70 * 0.02)
>  83: (2 * 0.10) + (6 * 0.05) + (75 * 0.02)
>  84: (1 * 0.10) + (8 * 0.05) + (75 * 0.02)
>  85: (10 * 0.05) + (75 * 0.02)
>  86: (2 * 0.10) + (4 * 0.05) + (80 * 0.02)
>  87: (1 * 0.10) + (6 * 0.05) + (80 * 0.02)
>  88: (8 * 0.05) + (80 * 0.02)
>  89: (2 * 0.10) + (2 * 0.05) + (85 * 0.02)
>  90: (1 * 0.10) + (4 * 0.05) + (85 * 0.02)
>  91: (6 * 0.05) + (85 * 0.02)
>  92: (2 * 0.10) + (90 * 0.02)
>  93: (1 * 0.10) + (2 * 0.05) + (90 * 0.02)
>  94: (4 * 0.05) + (90 * 0.02)
>  95: (1 * 0.10) + (1 * 0.05) + (92 * 0.02) + (1 * 0.01)
>  96: (1 * 0.10) + (95 * 0.02)
>  97: (2 * 0.05) + (95 * 0.02)
>  98: (2 * 0.05) + (94 * 0.02) + (2 * 0.01)
>  99: (1 * 0.05) + (97 * 0.02) + (1 * 0.01)
>  100: (100 * 0.02)
>  101: (99 * 0.02) + (2 * 0.01)
>  102: (98 * 0.02) + (4 * 0.01)
>  103: (97 * 0.02) + (6 * 0.01)
>  104: (96 * 0.02) + (8 * 0.01)
>  105: (95 * 0.02) + (10 * 0.01)
>  106: (94 * 0.02) + (12 * 0.01)
>  107: (93 * 0.02) + (14 * 0.01)
>  108: (92 * 0.02) + (16 * 0.01)
>  109: (91 * 0.02) + (18 * 0.01)
>  110: (90 * 0.02) + (20 * 0.01)
>  111: (89 * 0.02) + (22 * 0.01)
>  112: (88 * 0.02) + (24 * 0.01)
>  113: (87 * 0.02) + (26 * 0.01)
>  114: (86 * 0.02) + (28 * 0.01)
>  115: (85 * 0.02) + (30 * 0.01)
>  116: (84 * 0.02) + (32 * 0.01)
>  117: (83 * 0.02) + (34 * 0.01)
>  118: (82 * 0.02) + (36 * 0.01)
>  119: (81 * 0.02) + (38 * 0.01)
>  120: (80 * 0.02) + (40 * 0.01)
>  121: (79 * 0.02) + (42 * 0.01)
>  122: (78 * 0.02) + (44 * 0.01)
>  123: (77 * 0.02) + (46 * 0.01)
>  124: (76 * 0.02) + (48 * 0.01)
>  125: (75 * 0.02) + (50 * 0.01)
>  126: (74 * 0.02) + (52 * 0.01)
>  127: (73 * 0.02) + (54 * 0.01)
>  128: (72 * 0.02) + (56 * 0.01)
>  129: (71 * 0.02) + (58 * 0.01)
>  130: (70 * 0.02) + (60 * 0.01)
>  131: (69 * 0.02) + (62 * 0.01)
>  132: (68 * 0.02) + (64 * 0.01)
>  133: (67 * 0.02) + (66 * 0.01)
>  134: (66 * 0.02) + (68 * 0.01)
>  135: (65 * 0.02) + (70 * 0.01)
>  136: (64 * 0.02) + (72 * 0.01)
>  137: (63 * 0.02) + (74 * 0.01)
>  138: (62 * 0.02) + (76 * 0.01)
>  139: (61 * 0.02) + (78 * 0.01)
>  140: (60 * 0.02) + (80 * 0.01)
>  141: (59 * 0.02) + (82 * 0.01)
>  142: (58 * 0.02) + (84 * 0.01)
>  143: (57 * 0.02) + (86 * 0.01)
>  144: (56 * 0.02) + (88 * 0.01)
>  145: (55 * 0.02) + (90 * 0.01)
>  146: (54 * 0.02) + (92 * 0.01)
>  147: (53 * 0.02) + (94 * 0.01)
>  148: (52 * 0.02) + (96 * 0.01)
>  149: (51 * 0.02) + (98 * 0.01)
>  150: (50 * 0.02) + (100 * 0.01)
>  151: (49 * 0.02) + (102 * 0.01)
>  152: (48 * 0.02) + (104 * 0.01)
>  153: (47 * 0.02) + (106 * 0.01)
>  154: (46 * 0.02) + (108 * 0.01)
>  155: (45 * 0.02) + (110 * 0.01)
>  156: (44 * 0.02) + (112 * 0.01)
>  157: (43 * 0.02) + (114 * 0.01)
>  158: (42 * 0.02) + (116 * 0.01)
>  159: (41 * 0.02) + (118 * 0.01)
>  160: (40 * 0.02) + (120 * 0.01)
>  161: (39 * 0.02) + (122 * 0.01)
>  162: (38 * 0.02) + (124 * 0.01)
>  163: (37 * 0.02) + (126 * 0.01)
>  164: (36 * 0.02) + (128 * 0.01)
>  165: (35 * 0.02) + (130 * 0.01)
>  166: (34 * 0.02) + (132 * 0.01)
>  167: (33 * 0.02) + (134 * 0.01)
>  168: (32 * 0.02) + (136 * 0.01)
>  169: (31 * 0.02) + (138 * 0.01)
>  170: (30 * 0.02) + (140 * 0.01)
>  171: (29 * 0.02) + (142 * 0.01)
>  172: (28 * 0.02) + (144 * 0.01)
>  173: (27 * 0.02) + (146 * 0.01)
>  174: (26 * 0.02) + (148 * 0.01)
>  175: (25 * 0.02) + (150 * 0.01)
>  176: (24 * 0.02) + (152 * 0.01)
>  177: (23 * 0.02) + (154 * 0.01)
>  178: (22 * 0.02) + (156 * 0.01)
>  179: (21 * 0.02) + (158 * 0.01)
>  180: (20 * 0.02) + (160 * 0.01)
>  181: (19 * 0.02) + (162 * 0.01)
>  182: (18 * 0.02) + (164 * 0.01)
>  183: (17 * 0.02) + (166 * 0.01)
>  184: (16 * 0.02) + (168 * 0.01)
>  185: (15 * 0.02) + (170 * 0.01)
>  186: (14 * 0.02) + (172 * 0.01)
>  187: (13 * 0.02) + (174 * 0.01)
>  188: (12 * 0.02) + (176 * 0.01)
>  189: (11 * 0.02) + (178 * 0.01)
>  190: (10 * 0.02) + (180 * 0.01)
>  191: (9 * 0.02) + (182 * 0.01)
>  192: (8 * 0.02) + (184 * 0.01)
>  193: (7 * 0.02) + (186 * 0.01)
>  194: (6 * 0.02) + (188 * 0.01)
>  195: (5 * 0.02) + (190 * 0.01)
>  196: (4 * 0.02) + (192 * 0.01)
>  197: (3 * 0.02) + (194 * 0.01)
>  198: (2 * 0.02) + (196 * 0.01)
>  199: (1 * 0.02) + (198 * 0.01)
>  200: (200 * 0.01)